# Incorporate domain name in lstlistinput

Tags: fonts, code

I have some bash code which I want to incorporate in my document but I want to include the command followed by the output. For simplicity let yous the code `ls`. I have my code in a txt file which I call in with `\lstinputlisting[style=MybashStyle]{Code/foo.txt}`.

The problem I am having is trying to distinguish between command and output. Currently I have used the domain name i.e name@server:home/$ before any code but as they are all in the same style text it gets hard to distinguish where thing start and stop. Any ideas on how to call alter MybashStyle to recognize this sequence and either color it or make font bold etc.

Comment: You should show us some code you have tried. And please show us the `foo.txt` file.  If possible, can you mark in an screenshot what you want to be changed?